# How to insert a mix of explicit values and data retrieved from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know two ways to insert data into a table

Method 1 : explicit values

```
INSERT INTO table
('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Method 2 : copying data from another table

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'
FROM otherTable
```

Both work only if all the fields are populated the same way. I need to insert in the same row a mix of explicit values and copied data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is. (Note that in your Method 2 example, that would actually insert explicit values, and not data from the other table)

e.g.

```
INSERT SomeTable(FieldA, FieldB, FieldC)
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, 'Explicit Value'
FROM SomeOtherTable
```

Comment: Is there a way to insert multiple rows this way? That is, I want to insert ("a", "b', FieldA), ("c", "d", FieldA) ...

Comment: @Zxaos - yes, from SQL 2008 an onwards you can do this via Row Constructor: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2007/12/06/row-constructor-or-table-valued-parameter.aspx

Comment: So presumably it's a RDBMS specific feature then. Thanks!